# Multi-factor authentication for hybrid azure AD joined domain

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

my question is if It is possible to force the multi-factor authentication on Hybrid Azure AD joined domain configuration?
Use case: for example, one of my employees is on the airport's bar and he is going to connect to azure AD domain by a not registred device, he use is azure AD trusted credentials to connect. In this case I want to force the multi-factor authentication.

Thank you.
Kind Regards
Vittorio

Answer (score 1):

If using cloud-based MFA, then you don't need to use rules in the on-prem to trigger MFA. Instead, you can use Azure AD Conditional Access policies to trigger when MFA is required. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/untrusted-networks